# Find value in DataSet DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

This is a C# syntax question.

From the 30,000 foot level, I have a DataTable from a DataSet, and I want to determine whether or not a looping int is "in" the KeyID from this DataTable.

If I set a break point and walk through the code below, I have a count of 37, but there are only four rows of data in my DataTable.  So, as I loop through my 37 ints, I want to lod files ONLY where i can be found

```
for (i = 1; i <= iCount; i++)
{
    if (i in myDataSet.Tables[0].Select("KeyID"))  // this is the syntax I cannot seem to get right
    {
        // If it's there, then we want to read this file.
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq for this: 
Add System.Data.Linq reference

```
for (i = 1; i <= iCount; i++)
 {
    if (myDataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(i => Convert.ToInt32(i["KeyID"]) == i))
    {


    }

 }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that always iterate through the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

Acconrding to the [DataView RowFilter Syntax}(http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/):

```
var myRows = myDataSet.Tables[0]
                 .Select(string.Format("KeyID >= 1 AND KeyID <= {0}", count));
```